# How do I send message to WebSphere MQ using Apche Camel and Receive message from MQ Queue?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I didn't see enough examples on web using apache camel with websphere mq to send and receive messages. I had a example code but I got struck at the middle of code.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern;
import org.apache.camel.Producer;
import org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * Client that uses the <a href="http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html">Mesage Endpoint</a>
 * pattern to easily exchange messages with the Server.
 * <p/>
 * Notice this very same API can use for all components in Camel, so if we were using TCP communication instead
 * of JMS messaging we could just use <code>camel.getEndpoint("mina:tcp://someserver:port")</code>.
 * <p/>
 * Requires that the JMS broker is running, as well as CamelServer
 */
public final class CamelClientEndpoint {
    private CamelClientEndpoint() {
        //Helper class
    }

    // START SNIPPET: e1
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Notice this client requires that the CamelServer is already running!");

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-client.xml");
        CamelContext camel = context.getBean("camel-client", CamelContext.class);

        // get the endpoint from the camel context
        Endpoint endpoint = camel.getEndpoint("jms:queue:numbers");

        // create the exchange used for the communication
        // we use the in out pattern for a synchronized exchange where we expect a response
        Exchange exchange = endpoint.createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOut);
        // set the input on the in body
        // must be correct type to match the expected type of an Integer object
        exchange.getIn().setBody(11);

        // to send the exchange we need an producer to do it for us
        Producer producer = endpoint.createProducer();
        // start the producer so it can operate
        producer.start();
     
        // let the producer process the exchange where it does all the work in this oneline of code
        System.out.println("Invoking the multiply with 11");
        producer.process(exchange);

        // get the response from the out body and cast it to an integer
        int response = exchange.getOut().getBody(Integer.class);
        System.out.println("... the result is: " + response);

        // stopping the JMS producer has the side effect of the "ReplyTo Queue" being properly
        // closed, making this client not to try any further reads for the replies from the server
        producer.stop();

        // we're done so let's properly close the application context
        IOHelper.close(context);
    }
   

}
```

I got struck at this point of code..

```
exchange.getIn()
```

Do I have to use `exchange.getOut()` to send message?? and How to construct message using string and add headers to it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: @ShellDragon  updated the question please look at edited discrption

Comment: exchange.getOut gets you the OUT message from an exchange. It can be used to send headers/body, if the use case is appropriate. Perhaps you need to familiarize a bit with camel before solving the JMS problem. I have added links to some material to help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to familiarize a bit more on what camel is and how it works. `Camel in Action` is a great book to help you with that.

If you are unable to get a copy at this point, a [preview](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition) of the first few chapters of the book is available online and it should give you much better leverage. Source code repository for [chapter 2](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter2) should give you some more ideas around how to process JMS messages.